# EXTJS 6.0.2 - Disable button for File Field not working

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I am trying to disable the disable the button on filefield at runtime from viewcontroller but I am getting the error.

**Error in Component.js**

me.ariaEl.dom.setAttribute('aria-disabled', false); // Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null [ Seems me.ariaEl.domis coming as null]

**Error stack trace .........**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null
at constructor.onEnable (Component.js?version=20170809094755:4378)
at constructor.callParent (Base.js?version=20170809094755:1288)
at constructor.onEnable (Button.js?version=20170809094755:1786)
at constructor.callParent (Base.js?version=20170809094755:1288)
at constructor.onEnable (FileButton.js?version=20170809094755:165)
at constructor.enable (Component.js?version=20170809094755:3033)
at constructor.setDisabled (Component.js?version=20170809094755:4863)
```

I have a simple file field,

```
           {
                xtype: 'filefield',
                fieldLabel: 'Attach Items',
                buttonText: 'Browse Items',
                itemId : 'buttonid',
                buttonConfig: {
                    id : 'uploadmailwidget0Btn'


                },
           }
```

Trying to disable in viewcontroller as -
Code:

```
 Ext.getCmp('uploadmailwidget0Btn').setDisabled(true);
```

Can someone please help? Ask is simple, I want to disable the button on filefield from viewcontroller.

Comment: Which version of ExtJS are you working on?

Comment: Working on 6.0.2

Comment: Can you try .disable() method of file upload component.Reply if it doesnt work. OR can you create some sencha fiddle

Comment: Seems to work for me: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/24t9

Comment: I am really clueless what was causing this error. Disabled (or set hidden) should be working fine but it throws above error when the file element change its state. I tried to disable using viewmodel/setDisabled/ and comp.disabled = false ways but the error remains the same. Finally, rather than changing the state I remove and add new component to the container. That worked :)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is use [lookup](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/modern/Ext.app.ViewController.html#method-lookup) in your ViewController.

You need to add a reference to the button

```
{
  xtype: 'filefield',
  fieldLabel: 'Attach Items',
  buttonText: 'Browse Items',
  itemId : 'buttonid',
  buttonConfig: {
    id : 'uploadmailwidget0Btn',
  },
  reference: 'myButtonRef'
},
```

and use that reference in the ViewController to use `lookup` and change the disable value.

```
  function() {
    this.lookup('myButtonRef').setDisabled(true);
  }
```

Granted, I haven't used ExtJS much, but in theory this *should* work

Comment: I am able to get the handle of the button. But I am getting the error while I am trying to disable the button using button.setDisabled method. Even binding of the disabled : '{flag}' is not helping to disable the button

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the [ExtJS 6 documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/modern/Ext.field.File.html#method-setDisabled), the `setDisabled` method is private, so it is inaccessible.

However, we can do something like this. Keep in mind that this solution is not smart, but it works.
Test the [example fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/24sc).

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',
    launch : function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
            title: 'Hello',
            height: 200,
            width: 400,
            layout: 'fit',
            items:  [{
                 xtype: 'filefield',
                 id: 'fileid',
                 fieldLabel: 'Attach Items',
                 buttonText: 'Browse Items',
                 itemId: 'buttonid',
                 buttonConfig: {
                     id: 'uploadmailwidget0Btn'
                 }
            }, {
                 xtype: 'button',
                 text: 'Click to set disable',
                 handler : myBtnHandler
            }]
        }).show();

    }
});

var myBtnHandler = function(btn) {

    if (Ext.getCmp('fileid').bodyElement.dom.childNodes[0].childNodes[2].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].childNodes[2].disabled)
    {
        btn.setText('Click to set disable');
        Ext.getCmp('fileid').bodyElement.dom.childNodes[0].childNodes[2].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].childNodes[2].disabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        btn.setText('Click to set enable');
        Ext.getCmp('fileid').bodyElement.dom.childNodes[0].childNodes[2].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].childNodes[2].disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am really clueless what was causing this error. Disabled (or set hidden) should be working fine but it throws above error when the file element change its state. I tried to disable using viewmodel/setDisabled/ and comp.disabled = false ways but the error remains the same. Finally, rather than changing the state I remove and add new component to the container. That worked :)